# keep UIButton current state when it is disabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Hi i am making a custom **UIButton** which have images for **UIControlStateNormal** and **UIControlStateSelected**. But when i set `[myBtn setEnabled:No];` it changes back to **UIControlStateNormal** state instead of disabling at selected state. How can i keep the current state of button and disable it?

Comment: Just Checking it in my case it should work thanks and will mark your answer right as soon as i test it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to set like this,i hope this will helps you

```
[buttMR setBackgroundImage:yourButton.currentBackgroundImage forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

Comment: It did changed the the image but getting one problem "when an image is selected its image is of selected state. When i change it to disabled even when i have mentioned the selected image to be the disabled state image, it loads the normal state image". But if the button not to be in selected state when disabled it successfully loads the disabled image. Any idea how to solve this mystery?????

Comment: I solved that mystery but hard coding myButton setSelected:NO before just calling setEnabled:NO

Answer (score 5):

Use `userInteractionEnabled = NO` instead of enable disable.

Answer (score 0):

Set an image for the disabled state as well : `UIControlStateDisabled`

```
[myButton setImage:disabledImage forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

Comment: then i will have to check whether the button's current state was normal or selected then i will assign it to it.